# HP LaserJet MFP M426dw asks for password when scanning to email

Tags: email, passwords, printer, scanning

We have a HP LaserJet MFP M426dw on our network which is configured to scan to email. Apparently someone made some changes to this printer, and now the printer is asking for a password when trying to send the email.

When I enter the password for the management interface of the printer, the document is emailed correctly to the recipient.

However, in the past there was never a need to enter a password, nor do we want to hand out the password for the printer management interface to end users.

I've had a look around in the various settings, but can't seem to find a way to stop the printer asking for a password.

In "Access control" I changed the "Scan to email" setting from "use default" to "local device", figuring this would be a possible solution, but this didn't change a thing.

How do I configure the printer so it doesn't ask for a password when scanning to an email recipient?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is the printer asking for a PIN (not a password)? In that case, you can set if from the printer's web interface, as follows.

1. Click the System tab.
2. In the left navigation pane, click the Administration link.
3. Go to the Optional PIN area and delete the PIN

For more details see https://support.hp.com/rs-en/document/c03953891

If the printer is asking for a password instead of a PIN, try this method anyway, as the support document does not explicitly list the M426dw, so maybe that one is slightly different.